# How do you keep production site in synch with development site?

Tags: 7, configuration

I've got a Drupal development site where I test everything (modules, configurations etc.) before implementing on the production site. As it is right now, I need to write everything I do on paper and carry out the same steps on the production site.

How do you keep production sites in synch with development sites? Is there any handy modules out there for this purpose? To what extent can Drush help me out on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of approaches to synchronizing configuration between environments.

A few popular ones for Drupal 7 are:

1. https://drupal.org/project/features (recommended)
2. https://drupal.org/project/strongarm
3. https://drupal.org/project/configuration

For example with drush and features you can revert a component to the code definition with

```
drush fr my_feature
```

For more info on drush and features https://drupal.org/node/960926

In Drupal 8, exporting configuration has become much easier:

> With Drupal 8 you can deploy a configuration from one environment to
>   another. This capability replaces the need for various contributed
>   modules such as Features, Strongarm and Context.
>   https://drupal.org/documentation/administer/config

Comment: Thanks, the configuration module works very well. I had to apply a patch to get update statuses to work as they should; but once that was in place the module looks promising. Only thing I'm missing is block configuration, but the module does ease the task of moving configurations a lot still!

Answer (score 1):

David's answer is good.  In addition, you might also want to take a look at [Drush CTools Export Bonus](https://drupal.org/project/drush_ctex_bonus).  It uses the same underlying technology as features, but is designed with configuration management in mind rather than collections of features.  It supports block configuration.

Also, if you want to script simple block configuration operations (e.g. turning on devel blocks on a development machine), [drush_extras](https://drupal.org/project/drush_extras) now supplies some simple block manipulation commands.